# TRC20 curl for getaccount/getbalance

Tags: blockchain, tron, httpapi

What is the correct curl format to view trc20 balance of an account? I tried the below command, but the output showed no balance.

```
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8090/wallet/triggersmartcontract -d 
'{
"contract_address":"TCFLL5dx5ZJdKnWuesXxi1VPwjLVmWZZy9", 
"address":"TUT5SVvKmnxKpKdHi2tXMzPfffQNg7e3MU", 
"function_selector":"balanceOf(address)", 
"owner_address":"TUT5SVvKmnxKpKdHi2tXMzPfffQNg7e3MU", 
"visible":true
}'
```

output:

```
{
   "result" : {
      "result" : true
   },
   "transaction" : {
      "raw_data" : {
         "ref_block_hash" : "0d9745f14e11d7fa",
         "expiration" : 1605942390000,
         "ref_block_bytes" : "9c45",
         "contract" : [
            {
               "type" : "TriggerSmartContract",
               "parameter" : {
                  "type_url" : "type.googleapis.com/protocol.TriggerSmartContract",
                  "value" : {
                     "contract_address" : "TCFLL5dx5ZJdKnWuesXxi1VPwjLVmWZZy9",
                     "owner_address" : "TUT5SVvKmnxKpKdHi2tXMzPfffQNg7e3MU",
                     "data" : "70a08231"
                  }
               }
            }
         ],
         "timestamp" : 1605942331560
      },
      "txID" : "a3bdcb595a94f9805301fb74b33f2b536d3a6bb5050b7eb7b12808bb1e36fcd7",
      "visible" : true,
      "ret" : [
         {}
      ],
      "raw_data_hex" : "0a029c4522080d9745f14e11d7fa40f0d980cdde2e5a6d081f12690a31747970652e676f6f676c65617069732e636f6d2f70726f746f636f6c2e54726967676572536d617274436f6e747261637412340a1541cab799601a50938457902e1a31d3faa26ca1d76012154118fd0626daf3af02389aef3ed87db9c33f638ffa220470a0823170a891fdccde2e"
   },
   "constant_result" : [
      "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
   ]
}
```

I use the default [main_net_config](https://github.com/tronprotocol/tron-deployment/blob/master/main_net_config.conf) with `supportConstant = true`. Do I have to enable anything else in my config file?